# Two Bootstrap Carousels On The Same Page With Diffrent Widths

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two carousels on the page with diffrent widths one falls within a col-md-6 and the other within a col-md-12. Each have diffrent id's one is MyCarousel and the other is NurseCarousel.

The problem is that both wish to be 1040px wide and the second one in the col-md-6 overflows as a style is placed on the container of 1040px and does not try and fit in its container.

I have tried overflow:hidden which dosn't realy work when it goes responsive. I have noticed that every time the carousels slide the 1040px in the style tag get reassigned.

Most confusing but If I can't fix it I will have to download owl carousel and use a second one on the page.

Full Width:

```
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

            <ol class="carousel-indicators" style="bottom: 5px;">
{% for banner in home_carousel %}
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="{{forloop.counter0}}" class="{% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}"></li>
{% endfor %}
            </ol>

            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
{% for banner in home_carousel %}

              <div class="item {% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}">

                <img class="responsive" src="{% thumbnail banner.banner_image 1170x513 upscale crop %}" alt="{{banner.banner_alt}}" />
                <div class="overlay">
                  <h2 class="line1">{{banner.banner_line_1}}</h2>
                  <div class="line2">{{banner.banner_line_2}}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
{% endfor %}
            </div>

            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>

          </div>            
        </div>
```

Half Width:

```
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="bg-right equal-col">
            <h2 class="title">Nurse Of The Month</h2>
            <div class="margins">
              <div id="nurseCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">   

{% for banner in nurse_carousel %}
                  <div class="item {% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}">
                   <img class="responsive" src="{% thumbnail banner.banner_image 531x166 upscale crop %}" alt="{{banner.banner_alt}}" />
                 </div>
{% endfor %}

               </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text margins2">{{common.nurse_lead|safe}}</div>
            <div class="margins"><a class="read-more" href="todo">NOMINATE YOUR FAVOURITE NURSE</a></div>
            <div class="clearfix" style="padding-bottom: 27px;"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

What happens:

```
<div id="nurseCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="width:1040px;">
```

Further explination:

Sorry for your miss understanding me. Yes my page is responsive I am using bootstrap for this reason. I have placed two carousels on the page one within a 12 column and one within a 6 column. Both are responsive but it appears that the second one within the 6 column is acting as if it is within a 12 column as it pushes out of the right of the container. It does this by adding the inline style of width:1040px. My only conclusion is that the width of a carousel is not unique to individual carousels one one page and the styles applied within the bootstrap javascript apply to all on one page. I have decided to go with an owl carousel but obviously would like to know if in the future this would be possible with bootstraps carousel.

Comment: If you want to get an answer to this question you should first format your code and be more explicit in the text. What do you mean by "both wish to be 1040px wide"? A carousel can't with because it's not a person. If you want to say that you want to force them to have 1040px width, just say it. But why would you want to constrain a responsive carousel to a fixed width? I tried to read your text but I can't understand what you try to achieve.

Comment: I have added further explination, hope this helps.